# "Oyster perpetual"

Tags: meaning

A famous watch brand has a slogan (I suppose) inscribed on their products: "Oyster Perpetual". What does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Oyster Perpetual' is merely the name of the watch, like 'Macbook' is the name of an Apple laptop, for example.

The 'perpetual' refers to the way the watch winds itself whenever the wearer moves their wrist, meaning it never winds down. Perpetual means continuous or everlasting.

Comment: +1: I think part of the significance of 'Oyster' is that its casing is sealed as tight as an oyster - water does not get in.

Comment: Very likely indeed.

Comment: @MehperC.Palavuzlar Actually, "Oyster" refers to the mother-of-pearl used for the face. I believe this may have been replaced on lower-end models with a synthetic material.